# How to set field name in django aggregate?

Tags: python, django, count, aggregate

For example,
My programs:
`[{"name": "html"}, {"name": "css"}, {"name": "css"}, {"name": "css"}]` in database.

models.py

```
class Program:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
class ProgramCountView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        query_list = []
        programs = Program.objects.distinct().values_list("name", flat=True)
        for program in programs:
            query_list.append(Count("name", filter(Q(name=program)))
        result = Program.objects.aggregate(*query_list)
        return Response(result)
```

But error has been: Complex aggregates require an alias.
I want result like `{"html": 1, "css": 3}`

Comment: did the `append()` work to the `query_list`?

Comment: yes append worked to the query_list, but with query_list didn't work with aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store your counts and unpack them as keyword arguments when passed to `aggregate()`

```
class ProgramCountView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queries = {}
        programs = Program.objects.distinct().values_list("name", flat=True)
        for program in programs:
            queries[program] = Count("name", filter=Q(name=program))
        result = Program.objects.aggregate(**queries)
        return Response(result)
```